# MongoDB, array of arrays index

Tags: mongodb

Can I have an index on subarrays?

Sample document:

```
{ 
    'who': [['en', 'Thomas'], ['es', 'Alfonzo'], ['de', 'Helmut']],
    'otherField': 123
}
```

Query:

```
{'who': 
    { '$elemMatch': { '1': 'Helmut'} } 
}
```

I need an index for this type of queries. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered just storing the data as `'who': [ { lang: 'en', name: 'Thomas' }, ... ]`?

Comment: Yes, but I prefer using arrays if possible. (edit: I mistakely deleted this comment from yesterday)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using arrays like this isn't the best structure, because you're forcing several rather conditions on your data.

Something like this

```
...
"who": [{
  "language": "en", "text": "Thomas'
}, ... ]
...
```

EDIT: (Removed previous suggestion)

Then, as Jim Dagg pointed out, you could create an index on `who.text`.

Comment: If you use subdocuments inside an array like in your first code block, you can use a [multikey index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#multikey-indexes) against `who.text`.

Comment: Thanks. I know I can use index if I use subdocuments instead of arrays, but I prefer using arrays if possible. If I understand the situation well, it is not possilbe to index array of arrays so I must use subdocuments.

Comment: Apologies then, but you're never really sure how much the OP knows, especially for newish technology like MongoDB. :) If it is any consolation, this is a better data structure than using nested arrays.